# CNN padding and striding

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

In CNN, if padding is used so that the size of the image doesn't get shrinked after several convolutional layers – then why do we use strided convolutions? I wonder because strided convolutions are also reducing the size of image.

Answer (score 2):

Because we *want* to reduce to size of image. There are some reasons:

1. Reduce computational and memory requirement.
2. Aggregate local features to higher level features.
3. Subsequent convolutions would have a larger receptive field in the original scale.

Traditionally we have used pooling to reduce the size of image, like max-pooling. Strided convolution is another way to do this (and it's getting more popular).

Comment: yes.But why we use padding and striding together in one network as padding is used to increase size and striding is used to decrease size.Isn't this a useless step taken..One of either should be used right??

Comment: @AnuragKedia Normally we don't use strided convolution every step. We only downsample once in a while so with padding the output image size at every layer will be something like 512->512->256->256->128->128->... And it is easy to follow. Without padding it will be like 512->510->205->... It's just difficult to follow.

Comment: difficult to follow in terms of what?

Comment: @AnuragKedia Difficult to follow for researchers? Also make it easier for shortcut connection as in resnet or Unet. Most of the time those 1 or 2 row/columns of pixels just don't matter and people tends to keep it simple.